# How to work anonymous function in PHP

Tags: php

Afted reading the documentation on Anonoymous functions in PHP I come across something particular to syntax.

This statement executes the anonymous function in one line but I do not understand why:

```
echo (function () {
     return 'hi';
})();
```

I understand that the function is returning a string data type and echo'ing it but I am unsure to what the () delmiters around the anonymous function are doing. Can anyone explain?

Comment: So that the anonymous function can be multiple lines?

Comment: @Phoenix What does it mean? I don't understand you

Comment: An anonymous function is like a literal for a function. Where an int literal creates an int value, an anonymous function creates a function object, without assigning it a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than directly passing a value through to a method you can create anonymous functions.

```
$example = array(1,2,3);
(function () use ($example) { return $example[0] -1; })();
```

The () delimiters are used like BODMAS in maths where (4*2) + 2 would be 10. Your telling the compiler you want to set the closure before executing it.

The long version would be

```
$closure = function () { ....
$closure();
```

This works with class instances and other variations also like:

```
(new Object)->method();
```

(do this first) do this after you get the result of what's done first

Comment: Instead of adding a new answer, a note that as per http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php  an anonymous function yields a closure object, making it similar to `(new Object)()`.

Comment: when its 12:56am I can't word things as brilliant as that but I will take your approach to future answers @JonStirling

Comment: Interesting answer!!! For additional what can you say about this code:
`echo "start".true ? "if" : "else"."end"; ///output "if"` when i can write this code the next: `echo "start".(true ? "if" : "else")."end"; /// output "startifend"` need in explanation

Comment: You are outputting start as a string, you are then running a ternary expression around a true boolean which will always return whats after the ? and then finally concatenating an end string to it. The first line fails half way because you missed the () delimiters around the expression true @MaximPro

Comment: @KyleThomas Then why do not I get Notice, Warning or Fatal error?

Comment: Well, since you are concatenating inside an output, () is used here as a inline ternary expression, you could replace true with 1 == 1 and you'd get the same output. Its like writing a shorthand if else @MaximPro

Comment: @KyleThomas like this `echo "start".((1 == 1) ? "if" : "else")."end"`?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to *define and invoke* the function immediately. This is supported by PHP7+ only though.

An alternative for PHP5.3+ would be

```
call_user_func(function() {
    echo "Hi";
});
```

So, if you want to define a function on-the-fly, so to speak, and use it immediately - this is the way to go.

Comment: I probably did not make myself clear: I was talking about this javascript-like syntax. Feel free to edit my answer accordingly, my command of English is poor for that.